# Nestjs prod jwt auth work on local but not in server

Tags: server, jwt, nestjs

> this post has been edited several times, so I rewrote the post in more relevant ways

[!] all my code is stock [here](https://github.com/bouteillerAlan/blogAPI), see the `master` branch. Keep in mind : the code work on local but not in my server.

### Tl;dr

In local (whit `start:dev` or `start:prod`) everything work, in my server (whit `start:dev` or `start:prod`) my jwt validation not working. I get the token back but if i test it in the protected route i got a `401`...

### The log

Some log (in prod).

1 - I send a get request (via postman) in `domain.dev/api/hello`

```
Request Headers
  User-Agent: "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0"
  Accept: "*/*"
  Cache-Control: "no-cache"
  Postman-Token: "3940ba0e-3c60-4746-bb12-e06bf01df0bf"
  Host: "domain.dev"
  Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"
  Connection: "keep-alive"
Response Headers
  Date: "Sun, 27 Oct 2019 20:54:35 GMT"
  Server: "Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)"
  X-Powered-By: "Express"
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
  Content-Type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
  Content-Length: "12"
  ETag: "W/"c-Lve95gjOVATpfV8EL5X4nxwjKHE""
  Keep-Alive: "timeout=5, max=100"
  Connection: "Keep-Alive"
Response Body
  Hello World!
```

The server responde, ok !

2 - I send a post request (via postman) in `domain.dev/api/auth`

```
Request Headers
  Content-Type: "application/json"
  User-Agent: "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0"
  Accept: "*/*"
  Cache-Control: "no-cache"
  Postman-Token: "4391992e-788c-4780-b188-833999383704"
  Host: "alanbouteiller.dev"
  Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"
  Content-Length: 45
  Connection: "keep-alive"
Request Body
  name: "Hadock"
  password: "XXXXXX"
Response Headers
  Date: "Sun, 27 Oct 2019 20:57:14 GMT"
  Server: "Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)"
  X-Powered-By: "Express"
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
  Content-Type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  Content-Length: "212"
  ETag: "W/"d4-XWUV7P7Ft81OyIDhImoZoNDfnsA""
  Keep-Alive: "timeout=5, max=100"
  Connection: "Keep-Alive"
Response Body
  access_token: 
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiSGFkb2NrIiwic3ViIjoiNWQ4YTFmZGIyMDc3NTU0NjlmMjgzNDNlIiwiaWF0IjoxNTcyMjEwMDY3LCJleHAiOjE1NzIyMTAxODd9.hoe69wy86XXXXXXXXXXXXXghGVw8TEKmOA"
```

The server send me this log (via pm2) : 
[image]

In the code each log corresponding to :

- The red -> `auth.controller.ts`

```js
// give the jwt
@Post()
async login(@Request() req): Promise<any> {
    console.log(req.body); // the red
    return await this.authService.login(req.body);
}
```

- The orange & green & blue & purple -> `auht.service.ts`

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel('Author') private readonly authorModel: Model<AuthorInterface>,
        private readonly authorService: AuthorService,
        private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    ) {}

    // check if user exist in db, if is return user
    async validateUser(name: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.authorService.getAuthorByName(name);
        console.log(user); // orange 1
        if (user.length !== 0) {
            console.log({status: true, data: user[0]}); // orange 2
            return {status: true, data: user[0]};
        } else {
            return {status: false, data: 'no user with this name'};
        }
    }

    // check user and return token if user is valid
    async login(author: any) {
        const check = await this.validateUser(author.name);
        console.log(check); // orange 3
        if (check.status) {
            console.log(author.password); // green
            console.log(check.data.password); // green
            const compare = await bcrypt.compare(author.password, check.data.password);
            if (!compare) {
                // if check is not ok
                return {status: false, message: 'bad credential'};
            } else {
                // generate jwt payload
                const payload = {name: author.name, sub: check.data._id};
                console.log(payload); // blue
                const jwt = this.jwtService.sign(payload);
                console.log(jwt); // purple
                // save in db
                await this.authorModel.updateOne({_id: check.data._id}, {$set: {token: jwt}});
                // return
                return {access_token: jwt};
            }
        } else {
            return {status: false, message: 'no user found'};
        }
    }
}
```

Everything look like good... The token is the same in db and in response.

But; my function validate in `jwt.strategy.ts` is never call :

```js
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy} from '@nestjs/passport';
import {Injectable, UnauthorizedException} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '../conf/config.service';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(env: ConfigService) {
        super({
            // which the jwt is extracted
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            // the password module check the expiration, this class no
            ignoreExpiration: false,
            secretOrKey: env.get('secret'),
        });
    }

    // this function is call automatically by the @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
    async validate(payload: any) {
        console.log('----------validate');
        console.log(payload);
        console.log({ username: payload.name, userId: payload.sub, timeStamp: new Date() });
        return !payload ? new UnauthorizedException() : { username: payload.name, userId: payload.sub, timeStamp: new Date() };
    }
}
```

The `console.log` is not visible on log while this is the case locally with the same files :

```
// LOCAL LOG WHIT THE SAME BUILD FOLDER
{ name: 'hadock', password: 'test' }
[
  {
    _id: 5d7e6520c7e8fb43fcb1a1e5,
    name: 'hadock',
    password: '$2b$12$f8bUfYwr7jjPlDuIrKVtzuKMZRVVRWjUUIOJpdSaeoFv4PN5XQ57q',
    __v: 0,
    token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiaGFkb2NrIiwic3ViIjoiNWQ3ZTY1MjBjN2U4ZmI0M2ZjYjFhMWU1IiwiaWF0IjoxNTcyMTc2ODkxLCJleHAiOjE1NzIxNzcwMTF9.8RnXXXXXXXX2rjwXs'
  }
]
{
  status: true,
  data: {
    _id: 5d7e6520c7e8fb43fcb1a1e5,
    name: 'hadock',
    password: '$2b$12$f8bUfYwr7jjPlDuIrKVtzuKMZRVVRWjUUIOJpdSaeoFv4PN5XQ57q',
    __v: 0,
    token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiaGFkb2NrIiwic3ViIjoiNWQ3ZTY1MjBjN2U4ZmI0M2ZjYjFhMWU1IiwiaWF0IjoxNTcyMTc2ODkxLCJleHAiOjE1NzIxNzcwMTF9.8RnXXXXXXXX2rjwXs'
  }
}
{
  status: true,
  data: {
    _id: 5d7e6520c7e8fb43fcb1a1e5,
    name: 'hadock',
    password: '$2b$12$f8bUfYwr7jjPlDuIrKVtzuKMZRVVRWjUUIOJpdSaeoFv4PN5XQ57q',
    __v: 0,
    token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiaGFkb2NrIiwic3ViIjoiNWQ3ZTY1MjBjN2U4ZmI0M2ZjYjFhMWU1IiwiaWF0IjoxNTcyMTc2ODkxLCJleHAiOjE1NzIxNzcwMTF9.8RnXXXXXXXX2rjwXs'
  }
}
test
$2b$12$f8bUfYwr7jjPlDuIrKVtzuKMZRVVRWjUUIOJpdSaeoFv4PN5XQ57q
{ name: 'hadock', sub: 5d7e6520c7e8fb43fcb1a1e5 }
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiaGFkb2NrIiwic3ViIjoiNWQ3ZTY1MjBjN2U4ZmI0M2ZjYjFhMWU1IiwiaWF0IjoxNTcyMjEyNDI5LCJleHAiOjE1NzIyMTI1NDl9.MrjXXXXXXXXX4NLFNw
----------validate
{
  name: 'hadock',
  sub: '5d7e6520c7e8fb43fcb1a1e5',
  iat: 1572212429,
  exp: 1572212549
}
{
  username: 'hadock',
  userId: '5d7e6520c7e8fb43fcb1a1e5',
  timeStamp: 2019-10-27T21:40:47.206Z
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd need to share more code but I'll add my 2 cents anyway.  Here we see you are adding a bunch of CORS headers which is fine, doesn't seem like they're necessary as you're hitting the same web server with a reverse proxy.  Now, your issue seems to be with the JWT validation part of your application.

Normally for JWT authentication what happens is the auth server(your API) creates a JWT (Symmetrically or asymmetrically) with a secret and returns it to the consumer for use in future API calls.  I see that you're passing it in properly via the Authorization header.  Now, your issue is probably on the back-end for the validation.  What you need is a middleware that checks for the Authorization header, removes the **Bearer** portion of it including the space then it utilizes either your public key(asymmetrical) or your private key (symmetrical) and computes whether or not it is a valid JWT, if it is valid then proceed, else reject.

Feel free to respond here and I'll respond as much as possible.  You definitely need to share your entire request and the entire response that chrome logs, check the network tab.

Comment: Hi, if i use my nestjs app in local (via ``yarn start:prod`` exactly like in my server) all my route work fine. So i guess my token validation work fine too, no ?

Comment: @Hadock Post the middleware code that checks the JWT to see if it is valid.  Also, place some logs there to determine what is the result of the comparison.

Comment: i have added some log =)